# Вычислить наименьшие значения i-х столбцов матрицы деленные на наибольшее значение в i-х строках

Tags: c++

Можете мне помощь

Не понимаю как сделать программу на с++

Вот задача.

Дано квадратную матрицу А размером n x n. Заполнить одномерный массив B долями от деления наименьшего значения в i-м столбце матрицы А на наибольшее значение в i-й строчке.

Можете просто примерно написать как думать, а то вообще идей нет

Answer (score 0):

Задачу нужно порезать на кусочки по мере увеличения сложности, а потом из них скомбинировать нужное решение.

Сам процесс нарезки - неформален, нужно набираться опыта, чтобы уметь это делать.

Для начала, нужно научиться вводить и выводить матрицу. Это позволит убедиться, что у вас все корректно работает и вы можете контролировать данные, которые обрабатывает программа.

После этого, надо научиться искать наименьший элемент в указанной строке.

Подумать, чем поиск в строке отличается от поиска в столбце.

Последние шаги довольно просты.

Наверняка вы уже решали отдельные части от этой задачи.